# "Identifier expected" and "Illegal start of type"

Tags: java, identifier

I am getting "identifier expected" and "illegal start of type" errors but I'm not sure why.

```
System.out.println("Is Ann Foley on ship: " + queenMary.findPassenger("Ann Foley"));
System.out.println("Is John Jones on ship: " + queenMary.findPassenger("John Jones"));
```

Comment: Please offer more information. What program language are you writing? How do you get ther error?

Comment: Please add the exception stacktrace

Comment: Is that the whole program or have you ommited the surrounding class and method definition?

Answer (score 7):

These errors commonly happen when code is placed at the class level rather than inside a method. Make sure that your code is inside a method.

Answer (score 0):

If this code is inside main class: Look if code is inside

```
public static void main(String args[]){...}
```

or

if this code is inside some other class then put these

```
System.out.print();
```

statements inside a function.